# How should I access hash bundle file name in index.ejs using webpack DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, preact

I want hashed bundle file name in preact project.
in preact.config.js the output file is as `config.output.filename = "[name].[hash].js";`

Plugin is defined using `webpack.DefinePlugin()` as shown below:

```
config.plugins.push(
    new DefinePlugin({
      process: {
        env: {
          API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
          FILE_NAME: JSON.stringify(config.output.filename)
        }
      }
    })
  );
```

Is there any way to include the `bundle.[hash].js` file in index.ejs.

Comment: You don't need this. Include all your deps into `index.js` compile it with webpack and include as script `bundle.[hash].js` to your document.

Comment: using HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Comment: It is one of the possible ways.

Comment: no it didn't work with preact configuration i am using. To be more clear, I am using template https://github.com/preactjs-templates/widget . How can I output hashed bundle file and use that file name in script.src=`bundle.[hash].js in index.ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be solved via [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), all the options can be controlled through `options`:

```
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    delete config.entry.polyfills;

    // add hash to the file name.
    config.output.filename = "[name].[hash].js";

    let {plugin} = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, "ExtractTextPlugin")[0];

    let html_webpack = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'HtmlWebpackPlugin')[0];

    // not sure why but without this option it does not inject script tag.
    html_webpack.plugin.options.hash = true;

    plugin.options.disable = true;

    if (env.production) {
        config.output.libraryTarget = "umd";
    }
};
```

In this case, the template `index.ejs` will be used as [default](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md).

Comment: Note that the examples shown on the referenced plugin page are a lot simpler and closer to regular webpack usage.

Comment: I guess so, this is extended example of [preact.config.js](https://github.com/preactjs-templates/widget/blob/master/template/preact.config.js) that OP uses.

Comment: You're right - just pointing the way for someone looking for a more generic example of how to use the plugin. Apologies if it came off badly, can't edit now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this problem by creating a hash function by myself and exporting the hash function.

```
  const hashNumber = hashGenerator();
  delete config.entry.polyfills;
  config.entry.app = "./index.js"
  config.output.filename = "[name]."+hashNumber+".js";

  let { plugin } = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, "ExtractTextPlugin")[0];
  plugin.options.disable = true;

  if (env.production) {
    config.output.libraryTarget = "umd";
  }

  config.plugins.push(
    new DefinePlugin({
      process: {
        env: {
          HASH: JSON.stringify(hashNumber)
        }
      }
    })
  );
};
```

and including that hash in index.ejs file

`` script.src = `/bundle.<%= process.env.HASH %>.js`; ``